# Comparing type of fields of different layers in Qgis

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

Is it possible to have two property layer dialogs open at the same time? I would like to see the properties of two layer's fields at the same time.
I need this because when I want to join two layers by a common field I like to check they are of the same type. I am using 2.18.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the property dialog is modal (i.e. you can have just one open and you can't do anything else while it is open).

However, when setting the join, you have access to important information about the datatype. `123` for integers, `1.2` for floats, `abc` for string etc. I don't know whether they agreagate multiple types or not (ex: `integer` and `long`)

[image: Join Field Type]

Comment: It's a pitty and to me, unconfortable, not being able to do anything else till the dialog is closed. But thanks a lot for the straight unswer.

Comment: @Pescariz Agreed... Regardless of the software, I sometimes just take a screenshot of such window and use it later to make comparisons.